# How do I prevent an EditText from resizing itself when the user is typing?

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` and a `Button` set next to each other on the same horizontal line.  It looks great, except when the user enters a lot of text, the `EditText` is resized, and the `Button` is squished.

I have both `EditText` and `Button` set to `layout_width="wrap_content"`.  `"fill_parent"` messes up the layout, and I don't want to use absolute sizes if I don't have to - the way it is now looks great in both landscape and portrait, I just don't want the `EditText` to resize.

My layout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/homelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelartist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Find artists:" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/entryartist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
            android:editable="true"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okartist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Search" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

For EditText use

```
android:layout_width="0dp" - not required but preferred.
android:layout_weight="1"
```

And for Button dont specify `android:layout_weight`

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick!

What does the "0dp" signify for the width?  That it should take up all the available space?

Comment: Do not forget to remove (if present) `android:stretchColumns="x"` in your `TableLayout`, where "x" is the column position that contains the `EditText` you do not want to get resized automatically.

Comment: the weight for the button does not change anything, but the width 0dp does. thank you

Comment: Finally I have a live example why we should use 0dp rather than wrap content

Answer (score 14):

What I do is in the onCreate for the activity, measure the EditText first then apply its maxWidth.

You can do so using code similar to the following:

```
EditText someedittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sometextview);
someedittext.setMaxWidth(someedittext.getWidth());
```

Answer (score 5):

Give `EditText` a `maxWidth`. That should stop it from resizing beyond the width you provided. Also, if you want it to be contained within 1 line set the `maxLines` setting to 1 too.

Comment: Thanks - I don't really want to hardcode a specific maxWidth, since it wouldn't be the same for different orientations or screen sizes.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You need to add android:imeOptions to prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

for both EditText and Button. It will also work set for EditText but it is better to have it on both.

Answer (score 1):

you can define size of your edittext as it shows above

```
android:minWidth="80dp"
android:maxWidth="80dp"
```

or

```
android:layout_width="60dp"
```

or

you can apply a background image of size you want
but don't forget to define its height and width
with wrap_content.

```
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I couldn't get the above to work.  What I did, is take in the text from EditText box and then format it down to the max size that my screen could handle.  When I save this off to the DB, I will save it as display Text and original text.

If you go [to this page](http://androidknowhow.com/?p=30) I put a longer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be to set the android:minWidth and android:maxWidth equal to the width you want.  This way you will not have to adjust your layout to use the android:layout_weight.

For example if you want your EditText to always be 80 density pixels no matter how many characters you type in use the following:

```
android:minWidth="80dp"
android:maxWidth="80dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact query. But i had an EditText and a Button next to each other in a Linear Layout.
I tried **android:layout_weight="1" for EditText**
        android:layout_width="0dp"
And it worked just perfect!! 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The chosen solution works, but let me add a little complement:
if you use 
`android:layout_weight="0.15"` (the value is not important)
then
`android:layout_width="0dp"` if the `LinearLayout` is Horizontal
or
`android:layout_height="0dp"` if the `LinearLayout` is Vertical.