# EditText shrinking

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Problem:
EditText no matter what i will do always act like wrapped around text (he is fitted to text lenght and expand during typing). My intention is to have size fixed EditText.

Target android: 19
Minimal android: 10

I try to put EditText on MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        showActionBar(this);
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void showActionBar(Context context)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View searchView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.search_bar, null);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setCustomView(searchView);
    }
}
```

seach_bar.xml which is added in showActionBar method is layout\search_bar.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/appIcon"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

values\styles.xml:

```
<resources>
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>
</resources>
```

It looks like this:

[image: wrong look of EditText]

Comment: By size you mean `width` or `height` or both?

Comment: I mean width. Height seems to work properly.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _"Height has no meaning for me."_ . What i am asking is: when you say _"he is fitted to text lenght and expand during typing"_ does the height expand or the width?

Comment: Height is fixed. Width expands during typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries i figured out that only way to force EditText to fill whole ActionBar is to set its size to some very big number (eg. 10000):

```
android:layout_width="10000dp"
```

Because i didn't heard about such big devices it should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtViewSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>
```

Comment: woww.. what is difference between match_parent and fill_parent?

Comment: As far as i know fill_parent is for older android version. But this way doesn't work. I still have wrapped editText.

Comment: @AnilBhatiya try out the solution below

Answer (score 1):

Add the orientation of linear layout to vertical and
Copy and paste this code in your xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

**Using `layout_weight`:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/appIcon"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
    android:layout_width="0dp" <!-- recommended but not required -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_weight="1" <!-- add this line -->
    android:inputType="text" />
```

**Using fixed `width`:**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" <!-- recommended but not required -->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxWidth="120dp" <!-- value based on your desire -->
        android:inputType="text" />
```

Comment: Sounds resonable, but still nothing. Since we talk about weights...
When both element (ImageView and EditText) have weights eg. respectively 1 and 5 resizing is still not applied. I mean, eclipse shows all properly, byt this smarphone emulator acts differently.

Comment: should put weight only for the edit text but not  for the other.. please try a few things from here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1408781/827110

Comment: No way, this is some tricky thing. Only way to change size seems to be minHeight/maxHeight. No auto-fit doesn't work. Maybe there is some implicit override which i don't realize?

Answer (score 0):

Add minHeight to editText like below -

```
android:minHeight="175px" // Your fixed size
```

This will fix the size of editText.

Comment: Agree, but it can't prevent EditText against stretching. My intention is to have EditText fixed, but initially fitted to screen.

Comment: But max of which device? So many of them. The role of match_parent is to strech component to every device. And in this case it seems to doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:orientation = "vertical"
```

in

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

So it will take `"match_parent"` on EditText in account.

Comment: Did you mean android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: @rainbow yes. sorry for mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays i still don't know how it works. 
Anyway, if i use Amulya Khare advices in Activity all is right but it doesn't work at all in ActionBarActivity.